# Javascript array of bytes to binary string?

Tags: php, javascript, encoding, binary

This is my array of bytes:
`var $x = [108,181,183,176,140,239,53,105,104,47,47,21,147,67,96,87,175,35,67,97]`

It has a binary PHP equivalent of gibberish: ``` $x = "lµ·°Œï5ih//“C``W¯#Ca"; ```

Now, what I can use so that `javascript:btoa(SOME_ENCODING_FUNCTION($x));` perfectly matches `<?php base64_encode($x); ?>`?

Thank you!

Comment: Create a string using `String.fromCharCode()`, then pass it to one of the 100s of JS base64 implementations you can easily find on google.

Comment: Yes, `String.fromCharCode()` is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, $x);
```

will return the string to use in `btoa`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base64_encode function but the javascript version of it

http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode:358

PHP JS is a good project that aims to port PHP functions to javascript, so if you ever need a javascript function that does exactly the same as a PHP function googling "phpjs _function_name_" will often give you what you are after :)

Comment: Apart from not answering my question, if you test it, it won't work on binary strings. Using `btoa` because it works on bin strings and my project doesn't need cross-browser.